# Let $A=\{(x,y)\in\Bbb{N}^2|y\le x\}$,define $f:A\to\Bbb{N}$, by $f(x,y)={x(x-1)\over2}+y$. Show that $f$ is bijective.

Tags: abstract-algebra, functions

I have proceeded in the following manner-
Note that $f$ can be expressed as $f(x,y)=1+2+\cdots+(x-1)+y=S_{x-1}+y$ where $\{S_n\}$ be sequence defined by $S_n=1+2+\cdots+n$.
Now, $\{S_n\}$ can take values from $\{1,3,6,10,15,\ldots\}=B$ (say)
Observe if we want to have $f(x,y)=a$, for some $a\in\Bbb{N}$ we can choose $y\in\Bbb{N}$
such that $a-y\in B$ and suitable $x\in\Bbb{N}$ such that $S_{x-1}=a-y$.
But I cannot show that this $y\le x$. Intuitively it looks like this pair $(x,y)$ is unique proving the injective property of $f$. But how to show this map is one one? Thanks for assistance in advance.

Comment: Notice that $a<b$ implies that $\frac{a(a+1)}{2} + c < \frac{b(b+1)}{2} + d$ for all $c\le a, d \le b$. This would probably give the intuition why it is injective. If we take $f(x) = \frac{x(x+1)}{2}$ then given a $z \ge 0$, there is a unique $x$ such that $f(x) \le z < f(x+1)$

Comment: $c\le a<b$ and $d\le b$, Does this imply $c\le d$?

Comment: Not necessarily. What makes you ask that?

Comment: $a<b$ then ${a(a-1)\over2}<{b(b-1)\over2}$, it's ok. But how do you say ${a(a-1)\over2}+c\le{b(b-1)\over2}+d$ ?

Comment: Notice that $\frac{a(a-1)}{2} + c \le \frac{a(a-1)}{2} + a = \frac{a(a+1)}{2} = \frac{(a+1)(a+1-1)}{2}  < \frac{b(b-1)}{2} + d$ for all $1 \le c \le a, 1 \le d \le b$ such that $b > a$.

Comment: ${a(a+1)\over2}=1+2+\cdots+(a-1)+a<1+2+\cdots+(b-1)+b={b(b-1)\over2}+b$ (as $a<b$). But how ${b(b-1)\over2}+b\le{b(b-1)\over2}+d$?

Comment: Notice that $\frac{a(a+1)}{2} \le \frac{b(b-1)}{2}$ for all $a<b$. Then I am just adding a $d > 0$ to the right hand side of the above inequality, which preserves the inequality. I hope that clarifies.

Comment: Thank you I understand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have to show the following: Given a number $n\in{\mathbb N}=\{1,2\ldots\}$, there is exactly one pair $(x,y)\in{\mathbb N}^2$ with $y\leq x$ such that
$$n={(x-1)x\over2}+y\ .$$
I claim that there is exactly one $x\in{\mathbb N}$ such that
$${(x-1)x\over2}<n\leq{(x-1)x\over2}+x\ .\tag{1}$$
This squeezing is equivalent with
$$\left(x-{1\over2}\right)^2<2n+{1\over4}\leq\left(x+{1\over2}\right)^2\ ,$$
and this is equivalent with
$$x-1<\sqrt{2n+{1\over4}}-{1\over2}\leq x\ .$$
The last squeezing implies that
$$x=\left\lceil{\sqrt{8n+1}-1\over2}\right\rceil\ .$$
After $x$ has been found we obtain
$$y=n-{(x-1)x\over2}\ ,$$
and this $y$ obeys all constraints, because of $(1)$.

Answer (score 0):

$\mathbb{N} =\{1,2,3,....\}$; $n\le m$.

$f(1,1)=1$, $f(2,1)=2$; $f(2,2)=3$;....looks good.

$f(m,n)=(1/2)m(m-1)+n;$ $n \le m$.

$f(m,1)=(1/2)m(m-1)+1$;

$f(m+1,1)=(1/2)(m+1)m+1$;

Recall:

$(1/2)m(m-1)=1+2+..(m-1).$

$f(m,1)=(1+2+..(m-1))+1;$

$f(m,2)=(..... ..)+2;$

$f(m,m)=(....  .)+m=(1/2)(m+1)m;$

$f(m+1,1)=(1/2)(m+1)m+1$,

i.e. the gaps between $f(m,1)$ and $f(m+1,1)$ are covered by adding $n=1,2,...,m$.

Now backward:

Given a $k \in \mathbb{N}$.

Consider the largest $m$ s.t.

$(1/2)m(m-1) <k;$

This determines $m$; ($(1/2)m(m-1)$ is strictly increasing);

Then $n = k-m(m-1)/2$.

Hence $f(m,n)$ is bijective.